# NoHostAvailableException frequently occurs in datastax driver 3.0

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I am using cassandra 2.0.9 and recently moved to datastax java driver version 3.0.0 from 2.0.5. I have following exception occurs frequently after moving to driver 3.0.0

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Timeout while trying to acquire available connection (you may want to increase the driver number of per-host connections)))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:84)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:63)
```

Is there any connection problem in driver 3.0.0. My code to connect cassandra cluster is

```
private static Cluster constructCluster(String hostName,String port) {
        String[] hostNames = hostName.split(",");
        SocketOptions sOptions = new SocketOptions();
        sOptions.setKeepAlive(true);
        QueryOptions qOptions = new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM)
                .setFetchSize(500);
        LatencyAwarePolicy loadBalancingPolicy = LatencyAwarePolicy.builder(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().withLocalDc(defaultDC).build())
                .build();
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints(hostNames)
                .withLoadBalancingPolicy(loadBalancingPolicy)
                .withPoolingOptions(new PoolingOptions())
                .withQueryOptions(qOptions)
                .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5)))
                .withRetryPolicy(new LoggingRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE))
                .withSocketOptions(sOptions)
                .build();
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "host name {0}", hostName);
        return cluster;
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

use one cluster and one/few Session instence in multiple concurrent requests  scene .

Comment: actually i'm using only one Cluster and one Session instance for querying. Even though it occurs for me.

Comment: any new updates here? I'v got the same problems... Did you solved your problem Rish?